# Sega Genesis/Mega Drive emulation (Gens/Gens-GS)

Tags: emulation

What is the current status of Sega Genesis/Mega Drive emulation?  I'd like to get Gens or Gens-GS running on Raspbian, if possible.  How is the performance?

Since Genesis/Mega Drive Gens also emulates the 32X and Sega CD as well, feel free to mention this information, if it is available.

Comment: Currently this question solicits extended discussion. Consider altering it to ask a specific question, perhaps of how to install a certain emulator, instead of asking for a list.

Comment: Updated to ask specifically about Gens.

Comment: Nice. I would also be interested in this. I'll let you know when my next batch of SD cards arrives :)

Comment: @Jivings Have your SD cards arrived yet?  I'd be interested in any updates you have.

Comment: It's still one of the projects I want to get done. Currently I'm still [messing around with my micro-printer](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/2120/40). I wish I had more time :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment, my understanding is that you won't be able to get Gens to run on the RPi.  Gens contains x86-specific assembly, which won't compile or run on the RPi.

On the other hand, there are a number of Mega Drive emulators for ARM devices like iPhone and Android phones, but they're all OS-specific and won't run on the Pi either.

I did find [DGen](http://pupnik.de/dgen.html) which compiled and ran on my Pi, but crashed a few seconds in when the SEGA sound tried to play.

Comment: Is there another emulator that we should be pinning our hopes on, like PicoDrive?

Comment: From what I could tell, PicoDrive is closed source, hasn't been updated recently, and is more targeted at handheld devices like the Pandora.  Something like DGen which at least compiles on RPi is probably the best bet, short-term.  But then, I could be wrong :)

Comment: Try disabling the sound and see if it crashes. Possibly just a piping issue that can be changed in source somewhere. The same problems occurred on PC's emulators with various sound cards.